# Add custom markers to java editor in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I've been trying to add custom markers to eclipse editor for many many hours (days) and I just can't get it to work.

I can add problem markers well and without any issues by extending them on my own `plugin.xml`. It does everything I want EXCEPT the icon for the marker. I want a different icon.
Here's What I have:

`plugin.xml`

```
<extension
    point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes">
    <type
        markerType="Plugin.MyMarker"
        name="Plugin.MyMarker"/>
</extension>
<extension
    id="MyMarker"
    point="org.eclipse.core.resources.markers">
    <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.textmarker" />
    <!-- <super type="org.eclipse.core.resources.problemmarker" /> --><!-- if I remove this comment, all works... But I don't want that icon-->
    <persistent value="true"/>
</extension>
<extension
    id="Plugin.markerAnnotationSpecifications"
    point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.markerAnnotationSpecification">
    <specification
        annotationType="Plugin.MyMarker"
        colorPreferenceKey="Plugin.markerColor"
        colorPreferenceValue="100,100,100"
        contributesToHeader="false"
        highlightPreferenceKey="Plugin.markerHighlight"
        highlightPreferenceValue="true"
        includeOnPreferencePage="true"
        icon="icons/icon_mine.gif"
        label="My beautiful label"
        overviewRulerPreferenceKey="Plugin.markerOverview"
        overviewRulerPreferenceValue="true"
        presentationLayer="0"
        symbolicIcon="warning"
        textPreferenceKey="Plugin.tarkerText"
        textPreferenceValue="true"
        textStylePreferenceKey="Plugin.textStyle"
        textStylePreferenceValue="BOX"
        verticalRulerPreferenceKey="Plugin.markerRuler"
        verticalRulerPreferenceValue="true" />
```

`MyPlugin.java`

```
IMarker myMarker = file.createMarker("Plugin.MyMarker");
if(!myMarker.exists()){
    Activator.myLog.log(new Status(Status.ERROR, LOG_PLUGIN_NAME, 15, "There's no marker!", null)); 
}
myMarker.setAttribute(IMarker.SEVERITY, IMarker.SEVERITY_WARNING);
myMarker.setAttribute(IMarker.MESSAGE, "Txt:\nabc");
myMarker.setAttribute(IMarker.PRIORITY, IMarker.PRIORITY_HIGH);
myMarker.setAttribute(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, line);
myMarker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_START, searchStart);
myMarker.setAttribute(IMarker.CHAR_END, searchEnd);
```

The marker image is here: `icon="icons/icon_mine.gif"`

If I use the code as it is above, the annotation appears in the menu under the annotations (`General>Editors>TextEditors>Annotations`)option with the correct image and the correct options as I would expect it to be.

Other log messages that I placed in the code confirm that that code executes well same as the results if I just change that line I commented in the XML (see the XML comment).

But still, I can't see anything telling me if the marker is actually being applied or an error (or anything in the log or the console, on that matter). It is as if I didn't setup anything and nothing is happening.
Any help is welcome

Comment: Try without specifying `symbolicIcon`

Comment: @greg-449 Nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do check that the ids of each `<extension>` must start with the same substring as as the package of the project. I see you using `Plugin` as the package and packages usually start with low case letters.

Please try renaming the prefixes of the ids to `plugin.` (low case) instead of `Plugin`.